# serialize not working for me in drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-6

i am trying to insert data to database but it removing braces'{}' while inserting i am using this code.

```
<pre><code>
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);
$aa['alt']="happy alt";
$aa['title']="happy title";
$sldata=serialize($aa);
$sql="Insert into test(pval) values('".$sldata."')";
echo $sql;
db_query($sql);    
</pre></code>
```

my db structure is as

```
<pre><code>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `sl` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pval` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sl`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
</pre></code>
```

suggest me what is wrong here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Drupal uses `{}` arround the tables names**, to be able to do some manipulations on those names -- like prefix them, if you have configured it to do so.

So, you must not use `{}` in your query -- except arround tables names, of course.

Instead of brutaly injecting your serialized-string into the SQL query, **you must use place-holders** in it -- and pass the corresponding values to [**`db_query()`**](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query/6), which will take care of escaping what has to be :

```
$sldata = serialize($aa);
$sql = "insert into {test} (pval) values('%s')";
db_query($sql, $sldata);
```

Here :

- As the `pval` field is a string in database, I used a %s place-holder
- And the first value passed to `db_query()` *(after the SQL query itself, of course)* will be injected by drupal, to replace that first *(and only, here)* placeholder.

And, for more informations, you might want to take a look at [**Database abstraction layer**](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/group/database/6).

Answer (score 0):

instead of just serialize, you could base64_encode to bypass curlies being a problem.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

```
base64_encode(serialize($aa));
```

Then on the retrieving side of the data

```
unserialize(base64_decode($db_data));
```

Comment: Those `{}` are removed because of the way Drupal's database abstraction layer works ; it would be more interesting for @Sumant to learn how that layer works, instead of bypassing this *problem* this time, and getting trapped again the next one...